# Access violation when streaming video with emgu opencv

Tags: opencv, emgucv

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Emgu.CV;
using Emgu.CV.Structure;

namespace CrackleTest
{
    public static class Controller
    {
        public static Capture capture = new Capture();
        public static VideoWriter CaptureOutput;

        public static void Init()
        {
            capture.SetCaptureProperty(Emgu.CV.CvEnum.CAP_PROP.CV_CAP_PROP_FRAME_WIDTH, 1920);
            capture.SetCaptureProperty(Emgu.CV.CvEnum.CAP_PROP.CV_CAP_PROP_FRAME_HEIGHT, 1080);

            CaptureOutput = new VideoWriter
            (
                "output.avi",
                -1, //CvInvoke.CV_FOURCC("W","M","V","1"),
                30, //fps
                (int)capture.GetCaptureProperty(Emgu.CV.CvEnum.CAP_PROP.CV_CAP_PROP_FRAME_WIDTH),
                (int)capture.GetCaptureProperty(Emgu.CV.CvEnum.CAP_PROP.CV_CAP_PROP_FRAME_HEIGHT),
                true
            );
            capture.ImageGrabbed += SaveFrame;

            capture.Start();
        }

        public static void Stop()
        {
            capture.Stop();
            CaptureOutput.Dispose();
        }

        public static void SaveFrame(Object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Image<Bgr, Byte> video = capture.RetrieveBgrFrame();
            CaptureOutput.WriteFrame(video);
        }
    }
}
```

When I call the stop function I get an error message

> An unhandled exception of type 'System.AccessViolationException'
>   occurred in Emgu.CV.dll
>
> Additional information: Attempted to read or write protected memory.
>   This is often an indication that other memory is corrupt.

I'm not sure what the best practices are for streaming video from usb webcam in opencv.

Comment: The video file usually does get created however it seems to be corrupt. When I try to play it with vlc, vlc player seems to want to "rebuild indexes" before playing the video.

Comment: This does not seem to happen when I choose "Full Frames (Uncompressed)" as my codec.

Comment: For some reason this problem goes away when I use the X264 codec from the K Lite codec pack. Having said that ... surely this couldn't be a problem with ALL the other codecs ...

Comment: I've switched to the X264 codec and the problem seems to be fixed ...

Comment: I'm thinking of using GStreamer to save the video